# How do I check the DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have host, database name, username and the password given as form inputs like:

```
$form['dbname']->getData()
```

I need to check if these data is correct for the mysql connection. So I chose to use `mysql_connect()` to check this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($form['host']->getData(), $form['username']->getData(), $form['password']->getData(), $form['dbname']->getData());

if($conn) // ...
else // ...
```

But it displays some `mysql_connect() warning with no other specific message...`

What's wrong? Does the symfony 2 has any mechanism to check the connection?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses repositories and entities to manage the database. The programmer doesn't manipulate the connection itself (Doctrine).

You could try to check a connection using PDO. Try to instance a PDO Object, and catch exceptions (PDOException for connection errors). However, you're "breaking" the framework's philosophy, trying to initiate an "extern" DB connection. If you need to work with several connections in Symfony, I suggest this reference :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: you seems to be in favor for symphony i see :-)

Comment: Well, the author seems to be using it, actually... ^^ There wouldn't any point in using the framework and break it's native behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use the following format to receive the connection error if there is any.

```
$con = mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());
```